# Trying to select elements within a $(this) selector

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to select elements within a $(this) selector

I have several divs of a class .category_row_belts. Within each one is an anchor tag enclosing an H2 tag and an image.

when rolling over the div, i'm trying to use jQuery's .hover() and addClass() to create a rollover effect on both the H2 and img simultaneously. in other words, when rolling over the div, all it's elements light up. Obviously i have to use $(this) and trying to use children() but it's not working.

```
<div class="category_row_belts">
<a href="linkhere.html">
<h2 class="belts-cat-description" >Product name here</h2>
<img src="img/product-pic.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

my js so far is...

```
$('.category_row_belts').hover(
function(){
    $(this).children('a > img').addClass('rolloverborder');
    $(this).children('a > h2').removeClass('belts-cat-description');
    $(this).children('a > h2').addClass('rollovertxt');
},
function(){
    $(this).children('a > img').removeClass('rolloverborder');
    $(this).children('a > h2').removeClass('rollovertxt');
    $(this).children('a > h2').addClass('belts-cat-description');
})
```

Comment: Does seem like something that could be done with CSS -> `.category_row_belts:hover h2.belts-cat-description {styles}`

Comment: Oh, and try replacing children() with find().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.category_row_belts').hover(
function(){
    $(this).find('img').addClass('rolloverborder');
    $(this).find('h2').removeClass('belts-cat-description')
    .addClass('rollovertxt');
},
function(){
    $(this).find('img').removeClass('rolloverborder');
    $(this).find('h2').removeClass('rollovertxt')
   .addClass('belts-cat-description');
})
```